# Surface reflectance product - do I always need it?

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, land-classification, reflectance

There is a neat Surface Reflectance product of Landsat imagery. I know the difference between SR and raw products: SR presents calculated values, that are supposed to represent state of the Earth surface, while "normal" products are disturbed by all kinds of scattering on the way from the Sun to the surface and back to the sensor.

Now, I'm performing a land classification of terrain to extract boundaries between two types of land use. I have many images and this is unsupervised classification. **Do I really need SR product here?** Would I need it, if it was supervised classification? I suppose it's no in both cases, as I don't directly compare any values between images. I just need to know exact position of this boundary.

Comment: This related post/answer may be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/153406/8104

Comment: Thanks for a link to an actual research article. It was helpful.

Comment: Is the SR product harder to obtain for you than the "normal"?

Comment: Not for Landsat, but other satellites require you to process image by yourself, what may need significant time to get to know all details about the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want to delineate the borders between two land uses you don't need to worry about using images with atmospheric correction. In case your application really needs the surface values (for example, you want to see if after applying a fertilizer the NDVI increases or not) then you would prefer using that product